# How to hide css and js version details from weppalyzer in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

For security region, I want to hide javascript and CSS version Details. I Try a lot and remove all commented version in js and CSS file but no the success. this time version show on weppalyzer.

[image]

Comment: There will always be a way to find out what jquery version you are running

Answer (score 0):

As @Luca mentioned, software like [Wappalyzer](https://www.wappalyzer.com) and [BuiltWith](https://builtwith.com) can easily detect what version of jQuery you use, even if you remove version numbers from the code. They work by detecting syntax and patterns in the code that identify what version you're using - see the [Wappalyzer about page](https://www.wappalyzer.com/about) for more details.

As jQuery is always loaded on the client's device, it's easy to find out what version your website is running. It's the same with HTML and CSS.

Server-side software is much easier to mask, as you have greater control over what the server sends to the client. For example, you can restrict what information is sent about your Apache installation and server operating system - you can [read this article at Acunetix](https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/configure-web-server-disclose-identity/) for details.